# How to implement Parcelable for an Arraylist of Object which does not implement parcelable?

Tags: java, android, parcelable

I have a class which is in a Jar file, and it does not implement parcelable and I cannot edit the Jar file. I get the object as a response from the server and I need to pass it to the next activity using parcelable, This class also has other Class objects. How can I achieve this ?

Here is the code of the class :

//The class whose Arraylist I want to send to another activity.
//This class is inside JAR

```
public class MacroConfig implements IConfig, IData {
    private MacroIdentifiers identifiers;
    private ArrayList<MacroRel> relation;
    private ExecutionMode executionMode;
    private ArrayList<RuleConfig> ruleConfig;
    private ArrayList<String> instruction;
    private ArrayList<String> _type_id;
    private String type;
    @JsonAdapter(JsonConverter.class)
    private ArrayList<Extension> extension;
    @JsonAdapter(JsonConverter.class)
    private Expansion expand;

    public MacroConfig() {
    }
```

I tried things mentioned on blogs and other Stackoverflow questions but didn't find any proper solution to it.

Comment: "I tried things mentioned on blogs and other Stackoverflow questions".... Such as....? If you mention what you tried, then it prevents your question from being flagged as a possible duplicate

Comment: And can you not convert it to a JSON String? Why do you need Parcelable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be u can try this alternate way, From sender Activity:

```
intent.putExtra("myObject",new Gson().toJson(listObject));
```

in oncreate of receiver activity

```
List<MyObject> obj = new Gson().fromJson(getIntent().getExtras().getString("myObject"), new TypeToken<List<MyObject>>(){}.getType());
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but I need to pass an ArrayList of object not just an object.